# Irreducibility of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

In one of my proof for my assignment I reached a point where I have to prove that $x^9-t^9$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_7(t^9)[x]$. I am unsure weather this is irreducible. If it is, how do I prove it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}_7(t^9)$? Is it the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}_7[t^9]$

Comment: Hint: Eisenstein's Criterion.

Comment: @Rankeya: There is no prime element in $Z_7(t^9)$.

Comment: @AleksVlasev Yes that is the field of fractions.

Comment: Agreed, but there is a prime element in $\mathbb{Z}_7[t^9]$, which is a ring, not a field.